# Can I add any language in android APk?

Tags: android

I want to add Arabic language in my app for offline listening. Could it possible to add it during development so that a user don't need to download it separately?

Comment: You should at least search for answer first: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Answer (score 0):

Read about  android  values/strings.xml

With using this, you can translate your strings